# PHP fopen() won't write to txt files in some cases

Tags: php, permissions, text-files, fopen

I'm not sure if it has to do with my permissions for file writing, or if I'm just plain doing it wrong.

Here is my PHP code:

Note: this is located in `www.sitename/folder1/folder2/index.php`

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$fp = fopen("../folder1/test.txt", "a");
$savestring = $user . "\n" . $pass . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring); 
fclose($fp);
```

It doesn't work. It says it is unwritable.

I tried this too: `/folder1/test.txt`
and `http://sitename.com/folder1/test.txt`

The only thing that works is `fopen("folder1/test.txt"a");`, but that writes to `www.sitename.com/folder1/folder2/folder1/test.txt`, which is what I completely do not want.

Is it something I did wrong?

Comment: You need to create all this folders and check permissions on it.

Comment: permissions: world and group: read and execute
owner: read, write, and execute
folders are created already